# Числа прописью в виде "по первому", "по второму" и тд

Tags: c#

Есть ли какой то алгоритм получения из числа написание прописью в виде 
1 - по первому
2 - по второму
3 - по третьему

Пока что кроме того как разделить на по количеству сотен, десятков и т.д. ничего в голову не приходит

Comment: кроме файлика json + логика инчего в голову не приходит

Comment: посмотрите это, может быть поможет... https://github.com/meritt/rubles

Answer (score 1):

Ставим нугет пакеты [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer)

[image: пакеты]

Пришлось дописать расшир.метод

```
public static class HumanizerExtensions
{
    private static string _prefix = "по ";
    private static string _postfix1 = "ому";
    private static string _postfix2 = "ему";
    private static string _search_postfix1 = "ое";
    private static string _search_postfix2 = "ье";

    public static string FromOrdinalWordsToOrdinalTime(this string input)
    {
        string result = String.Empty;
        if (input.EndsWith(_search_postfix1))
        {
            result = input.Substring(0, input.Length - 2) + _postfix1;
        }
        else if (input.EndsWith(_search_postfix2))
        {
            result = input.Substring(0, input.Length - 1) + _postfix2;
        }
        else
        {
            result = input;
        }

        return _prefix + result;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
        {
            string strNumber = i.ToOrdinalWords(GrammaticalGender.Neuter)
                                .FromOrdinalWordsToOrdinalTime();

            Console.WriteLine(strNumber);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("==============================");
        int num = 3456;
        string numStr = num.ToOrdinalWords(GrammaticalGender.Neuter)
                           .FromOrdinalWordsToOrdinalTime();
        Console.WriteLine(numStr);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Получилось так
[image: пример выполнения кода]

Comment: спасибо, но желательно без доп библиотек, попробую разобраться